# Restricting RDP users to certain machines on Windows AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

We need to add specific users to our on-prem part of production that uses traditional Windows Server AD. The users should be able to RDP into one machine (MachineX) and only that.

I thought this would be a simple issue of limiting machines in the AD center (as on image) using the "Log on to.." dialog. I've added both the NetBios name (as described under "Computers" in AD) and the DNS name of the machine. In all cases I got a "Error code: 0x1107" from my RDP client on Mac (also tried from Windows RDP).

How can I accomplish this?

[image: AD]

Answer (score 4):

The user will also need to be able to log on to the machine from which the RDP connection is initiated.

The account must authenticate at the connecting computer first before the RDP session will be initiated.  If you prevent the account from logging on to the source, the RDP will never be initiated.

Comment: But it works right now, with our "normal" settings. It's only when I begin to restrict that it's either everything or nothing.

Comment: What are your "normal" settings?  I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: What I believe Semicolon means is that the "Log on to" list must contain the names of both the server and the client, even if the client isn't in the domain or is logged on with a different account.  This is surprising but true.  Try adding the name of the Mac computer to the list.